# I started using jupyter notebook recently and I'm having some problems with disk usage

Tags: python, memory, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3, disk-access

I created some notebooks to write some code but then the disk usage reach 100% and even when I deleted everything, the disk usage was still at 100%. Can anyone explain to me what happened?

I wonder if there's a recycle bin for everything I deleted

[my jupyter notebook workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNoV4.png)